# How to solve such a shortest path problem with multiple starting points and multiple ending points？

Tags: graph-theory, shortest-path

On a graph, there are multiple start points and end points. Each start point corresponds to more than one end point, and each end point corresponds to only one start point. I need to find all the routes from the start point to the end point on the map. Different routes can't cross, but allow them to overlap.

At the beginning I used the A* algorithm to find every single route, but the latter route took more paths in order not to cross the previous route. I want to know if there is an algorithm that can consider the total length of all routes.

[image]

Comment: I'd be surprised if finding shortest non-intersecting paths isn't NP hard.  The sentence "Different routes can't cross, but allow them to overlap" doesn't make sense to me. Consider adding a more precise description of allowable paths. Maybe some pictures.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English, I added a picture to describe.

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify what you mean by a "crossing path"

There seem to be two possibilities that I can see.

A.  A crossing path occurs at a vertex with four or more edges. One path uses two edges to enter and leave the vertex, the second path uses a different pair of edges.

OR

B. The vertices have x,y locations all in the same plane.  Crossing occurs between nodes when two edges intersect.

---

Algorithm:

- Loop over start nodes
- Use Dijkstra to find shortest path from start node to all its corresponding end nodes
- If no crossing occurs, finished for this starting node
- Remove crossing node ( A ) or link ( B ) from graph and recalculate crossing paths in turn.  Select cheapest.